# Generate Structure from Expression

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Being inspired from [Expression Templates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expression_templates), I was wondering if given a expression

```
Expr e = a + b * c
```

where `a,b,c` are Arrays which are derived from Expression Struct (look at mshadow example for more reference). Will I be able to generate a structure,

```
template <typename T>
struct Expr{
    void operator()(const T& a, const T& b,const T& b, T& out){
         out = a + b * c
    }
}
```

Which I can then pass to the function that traverses over those arrays and computes the expression at each position of the array.

Thank You Very Much.

Other reference : [mshadow expression templates](https://github.com/dmlc/mshadow/tree/master/guide/exp-template)

Comment: What are `a`, `b` and `c` in the first snippet?

Comment: They would be array's. Sorry I wasn't clear on that part.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to set a local variable `out` and then discard it.  Your `Expr` template is mostly nonsense.  I'm uncertain if you are saying "using specifically mshadow's expression templates" or "using the expression template technique".  I suspect the problem is you don't understand the terms well enough to describe the problem.  The short answer is, yes, you can convert per-element operations into vectorized operations using expression templates.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont So actually, I was planning for `out` to be the reference to the output array element. But I thought, given that someone can guide me towards getting the `struct` generated. I could figure out the exact details. I do agree that I don't understand these terms well enough. I meant using "expression template technique", used mshadow for a bit more concrete example. If you know a way towards the solution, please help. Thank You.